# Most efficient way of writing a DirectoryIterator for PHP

Tags: php, regex, loops, pdf

I currently have this code in PHP:

```
// RETURN FILE NAMES FROM VAULT INTO ARRAYS
    $vault_folder = "\\\\namespace\\namespace\\folder\\folder\\folder\\folder\\";
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($vault_folder) as $fileInfo) {
        if (strtolower(pathinfo($fileInfo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == "pdf") {
            if($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isFile()) continue;
            $files[] = $fileInfo->getFilename();
        };
    }
    arsort($files);
```

What I would like to know is if this is the most efficient way to write this statement.

At current it is searching a network location '`$vault_folder` and storing all the file names into an array `$files`.

The folder contains multiple files and I only want it to store PDFs in the `$files` array, hence the:

```
if (strtolower(pathinfo($fileInfo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == "pdf")
```

`strtolower` is included as one of the companies who creates some of these PDFs for us save the files as `.PDF` and not `.pdf`. It also needs to link back to the file later on in the code so it does need to be stored in the correct case.

Returning 7k files is taking 7 seconds, give or take!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), it might be somewhat faster than implementing the logic in a custom loop:

```
$files = glob('\\\\namespace\\namespace\\folder\\folder\\folder\\folder\\*.{pdf,PDF}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Regarding your current implementation, `SplFileInfo` already has a method to get the extension: [`getExtension()`](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getextension.php).

Comment: glob seems a good function to test. However the above statement will not include .PDF and .pdf files it will only add .pdf files to the $files array

Comment: Updated the answer to support both *.pdf* and *.PDF* (assuming you don't need things like *.Pdf* or *.pDf*).

Comment: GLOB seems to return results slower 16secs average for my query and 23secs average for GLOB, I am going to build my filename into a sql table and link in that way as this will be much more efficient

Comment: I've tried both solutions on a local folder and `glob()` was about 30% faster. It might have something to do with the path being a network location. Maintaining and using a database is probably a good idea if you need to do this lookup often.